# Set specfic host for one flow objects

Tags: mule, mule-studio

Im trying to set up my mule project with a specfic host for one of the flow objects.

I have 5 flow objects in my project, all of them calling the same host. But for one of them I need that to point to a different host

MyProject:

```
flow 1 - 4 =host ${something}
port =443
flow 5 =host some.domain.com
port =443
```

I can build my project and I can call the endpoint (flow 5) but in the response I can se that it writes out :443 in the host url which casues the call to fail. How can I get rid of the :port in the response url AND is it a better way to set up what Im trying to achive?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Add lines below on your properties file "mule-app.properties"

```
api.test1.host=apihostname
api.test1.port=443
api.test1.path=/api

api.test2.host=otherapihost
api.test2.port=443
api.test2.path=/api
```

Then on your flow global elements, you can add 2 HTTP Request Configuration.

```
<http:request-config name="API_TEST1_Request_Configuration" host="${api.test1.host}" port="${api.test1.port}" basePath="${api.test1.path}" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
<http:request-config name="API_TEST2_Request_Configuration" host="${api.test2.host}" port="${api.test2.port}" basePath="${api.test2.path}" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration"/>
```

Then you can use that global reference on your http calls.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is basiclly how I try to solve it but Mule is still sending port info in response url. This call is to get an oauth access token. If I call the service head on the token displays no port info but via Mule i'll get an access_token with an ISS url like https://some.domain.com:443. I need to get rid of the 443 at the end. That causes my token to fail